# How to write to a file and save it dynamically in java

Tags: java, java-io

I have a requirenment to write to a file rather than in System.out.println and save it at same time so that user can see the progress anytime by opening the file.

Right now I am using following code

```
     FileWriter fstream = null;
        File file1 = new File(logFile);
        fstream = new FileWriter(file1);
        out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
               out.write(msg);
     out.write("\n");
```

but it does not save the contents to the file unless I say Out.close();

FYI - 1. This is a Java EE application code. 
      2. I donot want to user Log4jLogger

Is there any simpler way to do this? Any pointers?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to call `close()` - just call `flush()`.

> Flushes this output stream and forces any buffered output bytes to be
>   written out.

Comment: I disagree with skipping close(). It is a good practice to call close() in a 'finally' code block.

Comment: I didn't mean that you should never call close.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is `OutputStream#flush()`. The sad answer is that in reality that is going to be hard to guarantee in a lot of Java EE deployments, with JVMs and virtualized cloud thingies where f_sync() has lost promises it once had.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it this way.

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(logFile, "UTF-8");
out.println(msg);
out.flush();
```

If you require that the output is made at particular time, use the `flush()` method. Moreover, with this way you can specify a encoding for the output file.